# Why is it that my first and final salt return the same thing?

Tags: python, hash

I'm learning how to hash in Python and I've come across this part where my first and my final salt will return the same output.

```
import hashlib


def obtain_password():
    password = raw_input('Enter a password: ')
    hash_password(password)


def hash_password(password):
    salt = 'first salt'
    second_salt = 'second salt'
    final_salt = 'final salt'

    first_alg = hashlib.md5()
    first_alg.update(password + salt)
    first_hash = first_alg.hexdigest()

    second_alg = hashlib.sha256()
    second_alg.update(first_hash + second_salt)
    second_hash = second_alg.hexdigest()

    final_alg = hashlib.md5()
    final_alg.update(second_hash + final_salt)
    final_hash = final_alg.hexdigest()

    print "Password: {}".format(password)
    print "First Salt: {}".format(salt)
    print "Second Salt: {}".format(second_salt)
    print "Final Salt: {}".format(final_salt)
    print "First Hash: {}".format(first_hash)
    print "Second Hash: {}".format(second_hash)
    print "Final Hash: {}".format(final_hash)
    return final_hash


if __name__ == '__main__':
    obtain_password()
```

As you can see for the salting I have three different strings, `first salt`, `second salt`, `final salt`. However when this is run I get the following output:

```
Enter a password: Testing!23
Password: Testing!23
First Salt: final salt
Second Salt: second salt
Final Salt: final salt
First Hash: 78db908227eceb53f3dccecaa52dd5c1
Second Hash: eda250daa7839eb0eda41630d9a08b27d97be344908999e63b0bd43069183a1d
Final Hash: f8d314290d48d6fbf1a21d2bf9b1e94f
```

Is there a specific reason why I'm getting that output..?

Comment: Cannot replicate this. Pasted into file, ran with `python`, same input but got the expect output (First Salt: first salt)

Comment: cannot reproduce, I got the expected result.  Vote to close

Comment: Same here. Can not reproduce.

Comment: If nobody can reproduce it, I'm just going to delete the question

Comment: Does anyone think it could have something to do with my Python version?

Comment: @YoYoYoI'mAwesome nope, can't be python. Is this all your code? Did you change anything before posting?

Comment: @limbo Yes, that's all of the code, no I haven't changed anything.